# Laravel 5.8 stopped sending email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Sending emails from my system has stopped working at all. .env settings are ok. I tried to run this code to test:

```
php artisan tinker

Mail::getSwiftMailer()->registerPlugin (
    new Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_Loggers_EchoLogger(false))
);
$to = 'youraddress@example.com';
Mail::raw('Testmail', function ($message) use($to) {  
    $message->to($to)->subject('Testmail'); 
});
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in /home/usuario/dev/dev-contaja/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php on line 127
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://redis:6379 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution) in /home/usuario/dev/dev-contaja/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php on line 127
Predis/Connection/ConnectionException with message 'php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution [tcp://redis:6379]'
```

I'm using use docker.

Comment: The mail host is not reachable.

Comment: I used the command nc -v 'smtp.myhost' port_number and the connection was successful.

Comment: The error message is quite clear, and nothing to do with mail. "unable to connect to tcp://redis:6379 ... Temporary failure in name resolution"

Answer (score 0):

In the following `httpd.conf` file, configure the `ServerName` properly.

`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Like below:

```
ServerName 127.0.0.1:80
```

or

```
ServerName sitename
```

This resolved similar issue I was facing.